# Stacked bars as percentage of whole matplotlib with dictionary

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dictionary like this:

`{1: {'a': 140, 'c': 173, 't': 128, 'g': 136}, 2: {'a': 145, 'c': 161, 't': 138, 'g': 133}...}`

And I would like to display as a barplot the percentage that each letter represents at each key. So the keys (1,2,3...) would be the x values, and y values would all be 1 or 100% or something.

Then the values corresponding to the letters a,c,t,g would be used to constitute a percentage of each bar and colored differently for each letter, and I can't quite figure out how to do this in matplotlib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward combined with `pandas`:

```
import matplotlib
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline
​
d = {1: {'a': 140, 'c': 173, 't': 128, 'g': 136}, 2: {'a': 145, 'c': 161, 't': 138, 'g': 133}}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').apply(lambda r: r/r.sum(), axis=1)
​
ax = df.plot(kind='bar', rot=0, ylim=(0, 0.4))
ax.set_xlabel('x axis')
ax.set_ylabel('y axis')
```

[image]